# WP7 WebControl Characters encoding

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7

I have this little piece of HTML

```html
<b>OBNUBIL�,</b> 
<abbr class="abbrev" title="persoană">pers.</abbr>
 3 <i>obnubilează,</i> 
<abbr class="abbrev" title="verb">vb.</abbr>
 I. <abbr class="abbrev" title="reflexiv">Refl.</abbr> 
(Rar; despre vedere, memorie) A se �ntuneca, a slăbi, a se umbri.  Din 
<abbr class="abbrev" title="limba latină">lat.</abbr> 
<b>obnubilare,</b> 
<abbr class="abbrev" title="limba franceză">fr.</abbr> 
<b>obnubiler.</b>
```

which I want to display in a WebBrowser on Windows Phone application written in C#. This piece of HTML is stored in a string: `str2.`
I used this line of code: `webBrowser1.NavigateToString(str2)`.
It works but `Romanian diacritics (ă ,ș ,ț,�, � ,Ă,Ț ,�,�,Ș)` are not shown.
How do I change characters encoding for WebControl from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-16 in Windows Phone?

```
private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Showing the exact error message is useful for debugging. In a finalized application, 
            // output a friendly and applicable string to the user instead. 
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        string textString = (string)e.Result;
        string fixedString = "";

        // This search returns the substring between two strings, so 
        // the first index is moved to the character just after the first string.
        string defStart = "cuvânt\">";
        string defEnds = "</span>  <br/>";
        textString = textString.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
        int first = textString.IndexOf(defStart) + defStart.Length;
        int last = textString.LastIndexOf(defEnds);
        string str2 =textString.Substring(first, last - first);
        str2 = str2.Replace("&#x2013;", " - ");

        // Remove tab spaces
        str2 = str2.Replace("\t", " ");
        // Remove multiple white spaces from HTML
        str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "\\s+", " ");

        //str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
        //BannerTextBlock.Text=str2;

        webBrowser1.NavigateToString(str2);
    }
}
```

I hope someone understand my problem and could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what for do you use c#? You tagged it, but there is no code with c#. If it is relevant, please add it.

Answer (score 0):

I just help you with my knowleges in Web environements :

if you display this type of char : "Ã©", "Ã®", "Ã", ...
=> data **was save in  UTF-8**, and browser think he's having to deal with **ISO**.

if you display this type of char  : "�"
=> data **was save in ISO**, and browser think he's having to deal with **UTF-8**.

PS: sorry for my english.

Hope I help you.